# File names and folder names don't match

Tags: shell, unix

I splitted a big file (2.8G) in a list of little files (284 files .txt) using the following string:

```
split -a 3 -C 10m -d 2 file.txt output_       
find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.txt \;
```

Then, I created a list of 284 folders since I would like to put each of the 284 files in the corresponding folder. The string I used is the following:

```
for num in {1..284}; do
  mkdir output$num
done
```

To copy each file in the folder, the string is this:

```
for i in *.txt do
  dir=${i%.txt}
  cp "$i" "$dir"
done
```

Now the problem is to put each file in the corresponding folder since the first file is named for example: output_000.txt while the folder is named output_0. This occurs for files from 0 to 100.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a padded number string e.g. `s=001`, you can convert it into a number using `$((s))`.

Try changing your script to:

```
for i in *.txt
do 
    prefix=${i%.txt} 
    num=$((${prefix#*_}))
    cp "$i" "output_${num}"
done
```

So `output_000.txt` will be copied to `output_0`.